# Liferay 6.2 Alloy UI Dropdown

Tags: drop-down-menu, liferay, yui, alloy-ui

Im trying to make this example work on my Liferay 6.2 installation:
http://alloyui.com/tutorials/dropdown/

But for some reason is not working for me, i have added the code on my view.jsp file inside my portlet, this is the code:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
`<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui" %>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li id="myDropdown" class="dropdown">
          <a id="myTrigger" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 8px">
            I only close on escape
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

And then right after that the Alloy UI code:

```
<aui:script>
YUI().use(
  'aui-dropdown',
  function(Y) {
    new Y.Dropdown(
      {
        boundingBox: '#myDropdown',
        trigger: '#myTrigger',
        hideOnClickOutSide: false,
        hideOnEsc: true,
        open: true
      }
    ).render();
  }
 );
  </aui:script>
```

What i get is the Dropdown link but i can't find the way to make the "I only close on Escape" dropdown when i click the trigger. Also (just in case this helps to get you guys an idea of what's going on) when i try the portlet on my website im not able to make any dropdown work even on the liferay dockbar, so i guess it's something wrong with the YUI code.

Comment: I'm seeing `a.Dropdown is not a constructor`. Since this is new in the latest version of AlloyUI, I'd imagine it hasn't been patched into Liferay yet. That's just my guess though.

Comment: I guess you are right, i was trying to find what AUI version is being used by Liferay 6.2 and my guess is that they are still using AUI 2 or 2.5. So maybe thats the problem, hopefully someone with more experience than me can confirm (or not) this. Thanks a lot @Origineil !

Comment: Liferay 6.2 uses AlloyUI 2.0 https://github.com/liferay/alloy-ui/wiki/Liferay-Integration

Comment: Great, so now is confirmed. Thanks a lot @stiemannkj1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is NOT possible to use the `aui-dropdown` in Liferay 6.2.**

According to the [Liferay Integration wiki article](https://github.com/liferay/alloy-ui/wiki/Liferay-Integration), Liferay 6.2 uses [AlloyUI 2.0.x](https://github.com/liferay/alloy-ui/tree/2.0.x). `aui-dropdown` was created in commit [e9b3a1035a36148f9ea75c15796d0d4d342a3452](https://github.com/liferay/alloy-ui/commit/e9b3a1035a36148f9ea75c15796d0d4d342a3452), and the first tag to contain this commit was `3.0.0pr1~164`,* which means that `aui-dropdown` is not in AlloyUI 2.0.x.

**Note:** it's not possible to upgrade to a new major version of AlloyUI in Liferay either.

*Found using:

```
git describe --contains e9b3a1035a36148f9ea75c15796d0d4d342a3452
```

Comment: @Lowtrux, No problem, I wish I had better news for you.

Comment: I guess i will just have to inject jquery for dropdowns @sitiemannkj1